# Integrating Doctrine with Apigility

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, doctrine, laminas-api-tools

I want to create a basic API for users with Apigility and using Doctrine, but I literally can't find anything on the internet to help me with that.
What is the best way to integrate Doctrine with Apigility?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Doctrine in Apigility Module : https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-doctrine.

Comment: I saw that but there are not information or anything like an example of the usage and I can't find anything on the internet, a tutorial, for example.

Comment: Yes, and I see that there are still issues with this module... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239204/how-to-start-using-doctrine-2-in-an-apigility-application-with-zf-apigility-doct).

Comment: That is a shame, unfortunately. I hope to find something that can help me with that cause I'm really lost. The source in the thread you sent isn't available anymore.

Comment: I will continue searching for a viable alternative in the meantime though (maybe such as manually configuring and using Doctrine within the API's controllers through setter injection for example).

Comment: I just receive a notification from the creator of the module, he said that he got inspired this evening and is going to write a good documentation for the module explaining everything about it this week. *yay*

Comment: When you get the docs from the creator of the module, could you post it here?  Thanks in advance!  And, in the meantime, here is a [link](http://blog.tomhanderson.com/2014/11/zf-apigility-doctrine-zfad-for.html?view=classic) to a previous article he wrote on how to set it up.

Comment: Of course, don't worry, it will be a pleasure to help and thank you very much, I'll be reading the article.